# Why did my 35mm film turn out muddy?

Tags: flash, film, 35mm, fujifilm, contax

This image was shot on my Contax G1 with Fujifilm X-TRA 400 film. Though, this was my first time using the Contax TLA 200 Flash - so I did make some mistakes.

However most of the shots turned out accurately exposed and colors were really clear and balanced...except for a few shots (like the one below).

What could have caused this image to be muddy? Is it an element in the camera/film? Change in settings while using flash? Maybe a scanning error?

*(click to expand image)*

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "muddy"?

Comment: By *muddy*, do you mean parts that are *blurry*? Or perhaps the *orangish color cast*? Or *something else*?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have used the term *muddy*.

What I think I'm seeing is several things, but I think it mostly relates to one key item.

There's no EXIF data, but it looks like you used a very large apeture maybe full open 2.8.

This in turn gave you a very shallow depth of field leading to much of the image being out of focus.

The wide aperature coupled with a low power flash results in a significant contribution of ambient light over a relatively slow shutter speed, partially negating the ability of an electronic high speed flash to freeze movement.

Lastly, a direct on-camera flash makes *driver-license-pictures*.

Comment: "There's no EXIF data"  That made my day.

Comment: I'm not sure why a simple statement of fact makes you so happy, but OK.

Comment: Very insightful, doubly so from a moderator. I'm clearly in the wrong place.

Comment: @Hueco the FUJI GA645Zi prints "EXIF" data on the frame border. Analogue EXIF does exist ;)

Comment: It was just a joke. I went ahead and removed it. I hope you’re not referring to me as a mod ... I don’t wear that hat around here

Comment: @TimStack fair point. I’ve seen the info on the neg but rarely on the print/scan.

Comment: @Hueco you don't wear the admin hat but what about the captain obvious hat?

Comment: @TimStack I’m known to put it on from time to time. Finally get to wear the bad dad jokes hat though so, been trying to get used to that one 